# Can't connect to remote machine via SSH - error: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, administrator

I've been trying to connect to the remote machine with the new **second admin** account but password was rejected. I'm very certain that I have typed the right password for the **second admin** account. After three attempts, I received the following error:

```
$ Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

There was a moment when it ask me about some Key. I processed to type yes. Which after three failed login attempts, I've have yet to see the Key option.

I just keep getting the above error. I think it wanted me to type in the current admin user (**first admin**) that was logged in. If that is the case, how can I add my **second admin** account to login in (via SSH) while **first admin** is logged in (GUI)?

I'v created the second admin user as so...

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USERNAME 
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USERNAME UniqueID 405
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USERNAME PrimaryGroupID 80
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USERNAME NFSHomeDirectory /private/var/$USERNAME
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USERNAME UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . passwd /Users/$USERNAME "$PASSWORD"
sudo dscl . append /Groups/admin GroupMembership $USERNAME
```

...and enabled Remote Login with the following settings...

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: what is in the server log?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the key in `.ssh/knownhosts` on your local machine and
the problem is that your `knownhost` key may be linking you to the original user, not the new one:

1. ```
   vim .ssh/knownhosts
   ```
2. Find the IP address of the server) → Remove that key → Save and quit
3. Try to SSH again